# Ruby On Rails.How send email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

I can't sen email from localhost. Here is my code.
At first I was generate mailer UserMailer.
enviroment.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :adress => 'johnoggy3010@gmail.com',
 :port => 25,
 :authentication => :login,
 :user_name => 'johnoggy3010',
 :password => 'secret'
 }
```

mailers/user_mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

def mail(user)
rexipients 'rexipient@gmail.com'
from 'johnoggy3010@gmail.com'
subject = "Hi"
body :user => user
end 
end
```

my controller:

```
UserMailer.deliver_mail(params[:name])
```

and template in user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb:

```
<h1>Welcome to example.com,<%= user %> </h1>
```

But somthing is wrong and I don't know what exacally...

Comment: I certainly don't know either.  Can you post what you are seeing when you send an email (error message, malformed email, something else)?  Incidentally, 'rexipients' is not how you spell 'recipients'...

Comment: I don't seeing any errors....

Comment: So what _are_ you seeing that makes you think something is wrong?

Comment: just a white display :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your setting correct.Here is the code for using gmail smtp :

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'your host' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => 'your full email addess like abc@gmail.com',
  :password       => 'your account password',
  :domain         => 'your domain'
  }
```

In your development.rb write this following line to see if there is any error happening:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

In your mailer first try to send this simple email:

```
  def deliver_oggymail()    
    mail(:to => "rexipient@gmail.com", :subject => ="hi")
  end
```

In your controller

```
UserMailer.deliver_oggymail().deliver
```

Comment: All settings is correctly. Idon't seeing some errors on display and logs. But it still don't work...

Comment: you can not see any delivery errors? have you received your mail into your inbox?You have to say something about your error unless its impossible to solve it.add that last line into your development.rb and restart your server and try to send and see your logs.

Comment: I restarder server and try again, but still don't seeing errors in logs. And email was not sended...

Comment: I don't write :domain parameter...for what it ?

Comment: and write this config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

Comment: remove the domain param you dont need it and url option is ok. send me your stack trace

Comment: ok.I should looking for stack trace in project/log/development.log file ?

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1077ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `deliver_oggymail' for UserMailer:Class):
  app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:18:in `rescue in check_user'
  app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:9:in `check_user'

Comment: where is `deliver_oggymail` ? Is it in your user_mailer.rb ?

Comment: yes.
I change cause this method...I deleted 'deliver_'.Here is how it now looking:
UserMailer.deliver_mail(params[:name])
but then another error:
NoMethodError (undefined method `recipients' for #<UserMailer:0x00000004a76710>):
  app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:4:in `oggymail'
  app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:18:in `rescue in check_user'
  app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:9:in `check_user'

Comment: I had edited my answer.Have a look.Give me a +1 so that i can chat with you.Its saying my reputation is not enough for start a chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28991/discussion-between-user2323194-and-john-oggy)

Comment: now this error:
A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message